# How do I make netdiag work?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

I'm trying to run the **netdiag** command to troubleshoot the internet connection but when I run it in cmd I get the following message:

> 'netdiag' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Also, I have tried typing "**net diag**", which gives me a syntax error, but that **NET** command seems to be something completely different.

Searching on google for answers gives me results that deal with Windows Server 2003; I'm on a Windows XP machine.

Comment: `nediag` is w2003 specific. Win XP does not include it, but if you detail your problem (with connection) someone may be able to suggest alternative tools for you.

Comment: I see, do you think I should start a new question or should I edit and update my current one?

Comment: I would just edit current one

Comment: can he install it with  w2k3 res kit?

Comment: You can download the XP version from MS at this link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914440

Answer (score 2):

NETDIAG is great for diagnosing windows domain issues, but I am wondering if perhaps you are looking for "NETSH" - the command line utility for troubleshooting and configuring network connections?

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netsh.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

On my machine the `NetDiag` utility was called `xpnetdiag.exe` located here:

`%windir%\Network Diagnostic\xpnetdiag.exe`

I first tried to install the update for XP from [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17811) site but when I tried to execute it I got a message box that basically stated that this utility was already installed with my Service Pack. (I have XP SP3).